# how to call a wcf service in curl?

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, curl

How do I use the command line tool curl for  call a wcf service / server is alive?. My binding service wshttpBinding. My service host in IIS 7.

Comment: What do you mean by `Server Is a Live"`?

Comment: With this services I wanted to check whether server is live or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "server is alive". If you only want to know whether the service is responding to *any* requests, you can send a request to the service base address (`curl http://your.host.com/app/service.svc`), and you should get the service help page back (just browse to it and you'll see what you'll get back).

If you want to check whether a certain operation of the service is working, then it will depend on your binding configuration:

If the configuration of your wsHttpBinding doesn't use message security or reliable session, then you can use something such as Fiddler to capture the request of a "normal" client (such as the WCF Test Client), then use curl to send the same request.

If the binding uses such a feature, then curl isn't the best way to do it, since there the client needs to send a few requests (handshaking for the security or RM protocols) before the actual request for the operation is sent.